# Arrays variable as elements in C meeting error in hacker rank problem of triplets

Tags: arrays, c, declaration

How to declare the array with variable as it's elements

Getting and error while solving hackerrank problem of triplets

Answer (score 0):

You could use this C++ Syntax:

```cpp
int a = 2;

int arr[4] = {a, a, a, a};
```

Comment: are you sure the OP is using C++?

Comment: @phuclv this is legal at block scope, since C99